# Using Vector Graphics as Icon in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

I have the following base class for `MenuItems` in my MVVM application

```
public class StandardMenuItem : MenuItemBase, IExecutableItem
{
    ...
    public Image Icon { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

where my initial idea was to use `Image` to back the icons I display on my `MenuItems`. I have now come to the point where I am starting to use these `MenuItems` in the front end of my application and have found a superb vector graphics library I want to use instead.

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="resources_icons_xaml"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Canvas x:Key="appbar_acorn" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0">
        <Path Width="22.3248" Height="25.8518" Canvas.Left="13.6757" Canvas.Top="11.4012" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 16.6309,18.6563C 17.1309,8.15625 29.8809,14.1563 29.8809,14.1563C 30.8809,11.1563 34.1308,11.4063 34.1308,11.4063C 33.5,12 34.6309,13.1563 34.6309,13.1563C 32.1309,13.1562 31.1309,14.9062 31.1309,14.9062C 41.1309,23.9062 32.6309,27.9063 32.6309,27.9062C 24.6309,24.9063 21.1309,22.1562 16.6309,18.6563 Z M 16.6309,19.9063C 21.6309,24.1563 25.1309,26.1562 31.6309,28.6562C 31.6309,28.6562 26.3809,39.1562 18.3809,36.1563C 18.3809,36.1563 18,38 16.3809,36.9063C 15,36 16.3809,34.9063 16.3809,34.9063C 16.3809,34.9063 10.1309,30.9062 16.6309,19.9063 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
    ...
<ResourceDictionary/>
```

My problem is, using these vector graphics via code does not seem straight forward. I know how to include such graphics in XAML

```
<!-- Include Resource Dictionary -->
<MenuItem Header="Show Difference Details" 
          ToolTip="Launch the grouped data file and analysis window." 
          IsEnabled="{Binding GroupedDataIsDifferent}"
          Caliburn:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ShowDifferenceDetailsAsync()]">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_column_two}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

but this is *not* my problem. My questions are:

1. How can I use vector graphics from a resource dictionary in my Icons/Images for my `StandardMenuItem`s?
2. If the answer to 1. is "you can't", how can I convert from a vector graphic to an `Icon` in code?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. I want to be able to pick up the graphics using code. So for my menu item I have a method

```
public StandardMenuItem WithIcon(Assembly source, string path)
{
    var manager = IoC.Get<IResourceManager>();
    var iconSource = manager.GetBitmap(path, source.GetAssemblyName());
    if (source != null)
    {
        IconSource = path;
    }
    return this;
}
```

my issue now is getting the correct path to the vector image I want. Lets say in my solution I have my vector image in "Graphics/Icons.xaml" and the resource is called "appbar_acorn", how can I reference this?

Comment: yes you can use the same, perhaps referencing by the key using a converter. using this approach you may not need to keep the view stuff in the view-model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go

start by changing the Icon property to string

eg

```
public string Icon { get; private set; }
```

assign the icon value as key of the icon you want to use

```
Icon = "appbar_acorn";
```

define the converter in resources

```
<l:StringToResourceConverter x:Key="StringToResourceConverter" />
```

l: refers to the converter's namespace eg `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"`

the usage

```
<MenuItem Icon="{Binding Icon,Converter={StaticResource StringToResourceConverter}}"
          Header="Menu"/>
```

result

[image: result]

here is the converter class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class StringToResourceConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Application.Current.FindResource(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

you may need to adjust the icon size and placement on canvas, in the sample above I removed the `Canvas.Left="13.6757" & Canvas.Top="11.4012"` but still it is little big for the menu icon

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have my vector graphics in a resource dictionary, lets say at relative URL "Grphics\Icon.xaml". My problem is how to reference the `appbar_acorn` resource using code behind. I am having to pick up the static resource via code. I have edited the question, thanks again very much for your time and help.

Comment: @Killercam, you can merge the resource dictionary in app.xaml and then you can find the same by `Canvas c = (Canvas)Application.Current.FindResource(appbar_acorn);`. if it is not possible to merge the icon xaml in app.xaml then use that same control in which you have merged the resources, in place of Application.Current. eg this.Resource etc.

Comment: Cool. Great. I have this working, using Uri's because I may want to retrieve resource from a different assembly. But now I have another problem! I will ask another question for this and hopefully you will be able to assist me once more. Again, you time is most appreciated...

Comment: I have asked another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949531/correctly-size-icon-bound-to-canvas-object).

Comment: You don't need a converter for this. Use a dynamic resource and the string icon value as the key. No converter needed.