# Correctly Size Icon Bound to Canvas Object

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, graphics

I have to following method that retrieves `Canvas` object from a Resource Dictionary using the named assembly and a relative URI and binds the `Canvas` to a `MenuItem`s `Icon`. This code to get the vector graphic `Canvas` is

```
public Canvas GetVectorGraphic(string assemblyName, string relativeUri, string name)
{
    var imageResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    imageResourceDictionary.Source = 
        new Uri(assemblyName + ";component/" + relativeUri, UriKind.Relative)
            ?? new Uri(relativeUri, UriKind.Relative);
    if (imageResourceDictionary.Source == null)
        return default(Canvas);
    return imageResourceDictionary[name] as Canvas;
}
```

The binding to my `MenuItem` is

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}">
    <Setter Property="Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ...
```

I have also attempted

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform"
                             Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

You can see I am both attempting to set the height on the `Canvas` to 16 x 16 directly and also by reverting to fill a sized rectangle, but this is failing - it just results in a blank image. If I leave out the `Height` and `Width` specifications the resulting graphic is too large.

I have also attempted to resize the `Canvas` when I read it from the dictionary via

```
...
Canvas c = imageResourceDictionary[name] as Canvas;
c.Height = 16; 
c.Width = 16;
return c;
```

But this causes the image to disappear.

How can I correctly re-size my `Canvas` object to fit my `MenuItem`?

---

Edit (**Partial Answer**):

I have come accross many many posts, but none that solved all the issues I was having in one post. The problems:

1. Not getting any images displayed using vector graphics. [SOLVED]
2. Getting images displayed but not correctly scaled. [SOLVED]
3. Getting images scaled and displayed but only one at a time. [SOLVED]
4. Imaged are scaled and displayed for all required MenuItems but know the top level menu items have an unwanted margin. [ON GOING]

How I solved all but the last issue was 1. use the correct image source for vector graphics, in this case i found that filling a rectangle did the job. 2. You can bind to the Icon object directly to get the images, but there is no real way of scaling these appropriately. 3. You can scale the images by using a rectangle, setting `Width` and `Height` and filling this with a `VisualBrush`, but this shars the resource among `MenuItems` so only one will ever show up. To get the Icons to be non-shared you have to create a static resource and set `x:Shared="False"`. The final XAML looks like

```
<Rectangle x:Key="MenuItemIcon" x:Shared="False" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Width="16" Height="16">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>

<Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/>
    <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
</Style>
```

**Outstanding Problem**

I now have the issue where the top level items are also shifted to the right (shown with red-arrow below) because the rectangle dimensions are hard coded to 16. However, binding to the `Witdh` and `Height` seems to cause the image to disappear again...

[image: Layout Problem]

I am now going to attempt to template the menu item and set the Icon area to auto-collapse. Any other solutions are welcome...

Comment: see if [this trigger](http://pastebin.com/iM6agQ6j) in MenuItem's style help you collapse the empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues were that Icons are shared if they are not contained in an external static container (see edits to question). The way I got this all to work in the end is to use the following XAML:

```
<Rectangle x:Key="MenuItemIcon" x:Shared="False" 
           Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Width="16" Height="16">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>

<Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/> 
    <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
</Style>
```

Where the default `Visibility` of the `MainMenuIcon` is set to `Visibility.Collapsed`. This provides the following menu look...

[image: Look]

Answer (score 1):

`Viewbox` can easily take care of such things by scaling the content to available size

so remove the size from the image and place the image inside a Viewbox

example

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Viewbox>
            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

if you want to restrict the available size you may perhaps apply the size on Viewbox

eg

```
<Viewbox Width="16" Height="16">
```

from [MSDN: Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A Viewbox defines a content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space.

Comment: Thanks, but this does work either. The image just disappears. I have used Snoop and I can see what is happening and by setting the appropriate properties via Snoop I can get it to scale correctly. Basically, If I set the Canvas size this works, but the underlying UI element (shown as "(Path)") in Snoop still has the size 32.111999. If I go in to the (Path) and change `Left = 0, Top = 0` and `Width = 16, Height = 16` it scales right an looks great, but I can access the underlying path properties using `canvas.Children[0].Height` it is protected...

Comment: @Killercam, your icon (Canvas) need to have the size (original size of icon for proper rendering) otherwise it is considered as 0 height and width and scaling/stretching 0 size does not make any effect. also you may try defining the same as `<Viewbox><ContentControl Content="{Binding IconSource}" /></Viewbox>`